Hide Levels From Hierarch - Power BI
I have the below hiearchy. As you can see in the picture, Exmaple 2 does not have Level 2 and in order to complete the hiearchy i have write the word Dummy. The hiearchy works perectly however i m wondering if there is a way to hide the word Dummy without losing any levels or data.
Any help will be appricatied.


what about replace dummy to null?

not a good idea. the level will be appear empty. imagine to have 5 empty level in a row.

You can think of a more appropriate word than 'Dummy'. Like 'N/A', 'No data', etc. You can also use empty character (copy - paste from Internet). The data will still appear blank, tho.
